# Microsoft Exchange oAuth - System.OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I've written a console app thats running as a service (using TopShelf) and using a while loop it continuously polls an office 365 inbox every 30 seconds to check for new messages. I'm doing this using oAuth and the below Microsoft libary

Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices 2.2.0.

I'm using the reccomended approach from MS to get the Access Token silently AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword & AcquireTokenSilent.

After about 5 days of running perfectly I'm getting the below exception form Microsoft library:

```
System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
   at System.String.Concat(String str0, String str1)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.OAuthCredentials..ctor(String token, Boolean verbatim) in \\REDMOND\EXCHANGE\BUILD\E15\15.00.0913.015\SOURCES\sources\dev\EwsManagedApi\src\EwsManagedApi\Credentials\OAuthCredentials.cs:line 79
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.OAuthCredentials..ctor(String token) in \\REDMOND\EXCHANGE\BUILD\E15\15.00.0913.015\SOURCES\sources\dev\EwsManagedApi\src\EwsManagedApi\Credentials\OAuthCredentials.cs:line 36
```

When I've traced this through its being generated by this section in my code:

```
                           exchangeService = new ExchangeService
                            {
                                Credentials = new OAuthCredentials(authResult.AccessToken),
                                Url = new Uri(rdr.O365ServiceURL)

                            };
```

I've got my exchangeService object declared outside of my while loop and then I'm instantiating it inside the loop so I can make use of the AcquireTokenSilent call, otherwise Microsoft refuse the connection and issue the below message back:

```
Error: Your app has been throttled by AAD due to too many requests. To avoid this, cache your tokens see https://aka.ms/msal-net-throttling.
```

Is this a bug in Microsoft code or can I do something better to manage the memory here?

Also the service that crashed out was upto 3.6gb memory footprint which is about 3.5gb too high.

Comment: Eeek!!!!  Ideally, you can avoid polling altogether ("Polling is Evil").  Consider an event-based design instead: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/notification-subscriptions-mailbox-events-and-ews-in-exchange

Comment: you should at least be using a "using" so it cleans up old instances automatically.  Because you're creating a new one every time and the old one is an object, it's not going away.  At the very least you need to destroy the old one.  A using block would do this automatically.   As a side note here:  This is conjecture because you're expecting us to debug code you haven't posted.   You should post that entire function not just a tiny sliver of it.

Comment: Destroying the old one means it cant acquire a token silently because the refresh token previously acquired for the client isnt valid anymore...

Comment: then you need to rewrite it so you aren't creating a new object every time.  You're creating new oauth credentials which apparently don't change ever, and a new exchange service.

Comment: _After about 5 days of running perfectly_: Seems like you're in denial. Just because your application hasn't crashed (or crashed the server) for 5 days doesn't mean that it's "running perfectly".

Comment: When I try to put it into a using statement I get this error: type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which others can use to re-create the issue that you're facing.

Comment: Saw similar behavior after switching to new Exchange ExoV3 module -- ~5 days of working properly and then started out-of-memory errors (in Powershell FaaS env). I was memory constrained in the server (hosted ~1.75gb), so bumped it and issue seems gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was nothing wrong with the code in question. Whilst not ideal (I'm going to look I to the notification stream approach instead of polling thanks @paulsm4) it still worked and the Exchange Service was not disposable, so could not be instantiated with a using block.

The issue was actually in the log4net framework where I had the memory appender enabled. I removed this from my logger setup and the memory footprint stays where it should be.

This project uses three separate loggers and they were all building up in memory even after it was written to the file.

The instantiating of the exchange object was just the straw that broke the camels back and a red herring.

The app is sitting at a health 14MB memory footprint now.

Thanks!